# Xubuntu: Restoring the notifcation area in xfce4

Tags: xfce

While playing with xfce4 (on Xubuntu) I accidentally removed the notification area which is placed by default in the right of the top panel. Is there a way to restore it back to it's original state without diving into the process of adding, placing and adjusting icons?

**EDIT**

Actually, I'm looking for restoring the notification area to it's **default original state** by restoring its state "meta data" stored in the my /home directory, how can I accomplish that with the command line? Where should I go and what should I restore?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just one widget, so you can just add the Notification Area panel item using the Panel configuration. You can drag-and-drop it in XFCE4 in versions prior to 4.8. With 4.8 you there is a `+` putton in the Items tab.

Comment: I edited my question so it reflects more clearly my concerns.

Comment: Oh, in that case try this: `cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml`. But do it when not using xfce (say from the text console), or else it will overwrite it when it exits.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, try moving ~/.config/xfce4/panel to another directory (e.g. ~/tmp/): `mkdir -p ~/tmp; mv ~/.config/xfce4/panel ~/tmp/`.

But a more "safe" way would be to create a new panel (right click on the panel and choose "Customize Panel...".  From there, create a new panel with the appearance and position of the one you have now.  When that has been created, delete the first panel.